# What's a nonetype? don't really understand

Tags: python, debugging, nonetype

simplified  it for the post (most "" is actual code in my program that is fully functional):

```
studentName = ""

def getExamPoints (total):

"calculates examPoints here"

def getHomeworkPoints (total):
"calculates hwPoints here"

def getProjectPoints (total):
"calculates projectPoints here"

def computeGrade ():
if studentScore>=90:
     grade='A'
elif studentScore>=80:
        grade='B'
elif studentScore>=70:
        grade='C'
elif studentScore>=60:
        grade='D'
else:
    grade='F'


def main():

classAverage = 0.0      # All below is pre-given/ required code
classAvgGrade = "C"

studentScore = 0.0
classTotal = 0.0
studentCount = 0
gradeReport = "\n\nStudent\tScore\tGrade\n============================\n"

studentName = raw_input ("Enter the next student's name, 'quit' when done: ")

while studentName != "quit":

    studentCount = studentCount + 1

    examPoints = getExamPoints (studentName)
    hwPoints = getHomeworkPoints (studentName)
    projectPoints = getProjectPoints  (studentName)

    studentScore = examPoints + hwPoints + projectPoints #(<---- heres where my problem is!)

    studentGrade = computeGrade (studentScore)


main()
```

it keeps on saying:

> File "/home/hilld5/DenicaHillPP4.py", line 65, in main
>       studentScore = examPoints + hwPoints + projectPoints
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and
>   'NoneType'

I've never learned about or heard of nontype errors, and even when googling it didn't really get an understanding. Anyone who thinks they understand what's happening/ know what nonetype is?

Answer (score 4):

That's just Python's way of saying that the values were `None` (`NoneType` is "the type of the value `None`").

The reason they're `None` is because your functions don't actually `return` a value, so assigning the result of calling the function just assigns `None`.

As an example:

```
>>> def foo():
...   x = 1
...
>>> print foo()
None
>>> def bar():
...   x = 1
...   return x
...
>>> print bar()
1
```

Comment: if this is the code, whats missing it so it retrns 'none':     'code' def getExamPoints (total):
 total = 0.0
 for i in range (4):
  examPoints = input ("Enter exam " + str(i+1) + " score for " + studentName + ": ")
 total += int(examPoints)
 total = total/.50  
 total = total * 100  'code'

Comment: btw the nonetype makes total sense now, thanks for explaining it so well

Answer (score 1):

`NoneType` is the type of `None`. Simple as that. It means that you're doing something like this:

```
a = b = None
c = a + b
```